# $f_{n}$ converges uniformly to $f$ when $f_{n}(x) ≥ f_{n+1}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $f_{n}$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $[0, 1]$, which converges pointwise to a function $f$. And for all $x ∈ [0, 1]$ and all $n$, $f_{n}(x) ≥ f_{n+1}(x)$. Must $f$ be continuous?

I think the most natural way to prove it is to show this convergence is uniform. But I didn't have any idea so far, can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 3):

$f_n(x)=x^{n}$ is a counter-example. Here $f(x)=1$ for $x=1$ and $0$ for $x<1$.

Comment: Oh yes, that's true.

Comment: How about a variation of this problem. If we set the limit of the convergence $f=0$ on $[0,1]$, and $f_{n}(x) ≥ f_{n+1}(x)$, is the convergence uniform?

Comment: Then we have uniform convergence. It is a special case of Dini's Theorem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem @YiPing

Comment: Got it, thank you :)